# Can't get range from a defined name

Tags: excel, office-js

Excel 2016 (Office 365) 32 bits, 16.0.6965.2115, Visual Studio 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
I'm quite sure the statement below used to work, but now it doesn't work anymore:

```
var range = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("Countries").getRange();
```

I get an error stating that there is no support for getRange method, but it should be supported as documented [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/nameditem.md).
What am I'm doing wrong?

--- EDIT: this is the code I'm using ---

```
function paintRange() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var range = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("Countries").getRange();
        range.format.fill = "green";

        return ctx.sync();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        app.showNotification("Error", error);
    })
}
```

paintRange is attached to a button. There is a global scope defined name called Countries. 
I don't have any more details of the error besides the one I mentioned, I also tried opening the quick watch window to get more clues.

Comment: Could you paste in the exact error message?  In particular, is it a JavaScript runtime error that you're getting, or an API error object (has a debugInfo priperty, etc.)?

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: The issue is fixed with an update to the CDN.**  You should be able to use `namedItem.getRange()` now.  Thanks for reporting the issue, and allowing us to do a quick turn-around on it.

================

Felipe, looks like you're absolutely right.  This is definitely a bug.  Let me talk to the right folks to get this regression fixed as soon as we can.  I'll see if we can put in some processes to avoid this in the future, as well.

From an immediate-workaround perspective, two options:

1. Use the BETA CDN (esp if it's for an in-development add-in, rather than a production one).  That URL is: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js
2. Do a temporarily filling in of the inadvertently-removed getRange functionality.  Inside of `Office.initialize`, include the following code:

   ```
   if (!Excel.NamedItem.prototype.getRange) {
       Excel.NamedItem.prototype.getRange=function () {
           return new Excel.Range(this.context,
               OfficeExtension.ObjectPathFactory.createMethodObjectPath(
                   this.context, this, "GetRange",
                   OfficeExtension.OperationType.Read, [], false, true, null
               )
           );
       };
   }
   ```

The workaround in #2 should not cause harm even after the functionality is restored, but I would none-the-less recommend making a mental note to remove this after we've fixed the issue.  I'll update this thread once we have fixed the underlying bug, hopefully within a weeks' time (as a very rough estimate, pending any complications that might delay it).

Thanks for bringing it to our attention -- both the individual bug, and the underlying process that let the regression to this one API go unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Workaround #1 worked for me. This question is solved.
I might have found another bug. When I try to change range.format.fill property, JavaScript raises an error stating that I can't change a read-only property value in strict mode. Maybe format (or fill) object is internally declared as a read-only property and should be read/write?
When I try using range.clear, I have success, tough, that's why I assume the error is either in format or fill, but not on range.
Where can I fill these bugs? I think you showed us several times in the past, but I can't remeber right now, sorry.

Comment: Asking a question on StackOverflow, one question per topic, is the best way.  Please start a separate thread for the range.format

Comment: **UPDATE: The issue is fixed with an update to the CDN.**  You should be able to use `namedItem.getRange()` now.  Thanks for reporting the issue, and allowing us to do a quick turn-around on it.