# Office-js doesn't display the properties

Tags: excel, visual-studio, intellisense, add-in, office-js

I was trying to repro a tutorial about the creation of an Excel Add-in when something get wrong with the IntelliSense of Visual Studio. I was writing this code:

```
function updateStocks() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var **range** = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("Stocks")
```

At this step, everything was fine, but after the `getItem`, I have tried to add `.getRange()` at which point the `IntelliSense` was not able to understand anything related to my variable `range`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yifyg.png)

What is really "funny" is the fact that even if the properties are not displayed, when I write the code of the tutorial manually, the code is executed without mistake.

Why does this behavior occur and how can I correct it?

Comment: Hi Frederic Le Guen, does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see IntelliSense for other types within that `.run`?  I.e., do you have everything up to the point where you get a Range from a named item?  If you were to obtain the range differently (e.g., `context.workbook.getSelectedRange()`), do you get IntelliSense then?

This might be related to an issue (now fixed) where the CDN accidentally had the `namedItem.getRange` method removed (it was the only one that was affected, and we've put in measures to ensure we catch those in the future).  See "[Can't get range from a defined name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434857/cant-get-range-from-a-defined-name/41460597#41460597)".  The CDN has been patched a couple weeks ago, but the JS IntelliSense file ("VSDOC") probably hadn't.  If that's the case, it's a point-in-time issue that should resolve itself very very soon, as new deployments of the CDN *will* have the `getRange` method both in the VSDOC and everywhere else.

FWIW, you may still run into limitations of the JS IntelliSense engine (there are plenty, unfortunately:  for example, trying to pass values across Promises, or passing in API objects as parameters to functions).  The only true good workaround for this is using TypeScript, which allows you to declaratively assert to the compiler/IntelliSense-engine that *"I know this type is an Excel.Range!"*) -- and offers a number of other goodies, `async/await` being a very major one.  I personally believe that if you really want a "premier" Office.js-coding experience, TypeScript is the way to go.  To that end, I describe how to use TypeScript in my book, ["Building Office Add-ins using Office.js"](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins) (full disclosure, I am the author; but I've had many readers comment on how helpful of a resource it's been to them).  The book is very much TypeScript-oriented, IntelliSense being one of the reasons (and `async/await` and `let` being the primary others) -- though I also offer an Appendix where I describe the JavaScript-only way of accomplishing the same Office.js tasks.  It takes only a small amount of effort to get started with using TypeScript, and once you do, I don't think you'll look back.